# Styles not applying to button using tailwiind and next.js

Tags: button, next.js, tailwind-css

```
<button disabled={!session} 
className={`button mt-2 ${!session && "from-gray-300 to-gray-500 border-gray-200 text-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed"}`}>
{!session ? 'Sign In to checkout' : 'Proceed to checkout'}
</button>
```

This is the code for it

Expected a gray background with a disabled button but got the following output -

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tcaw.png)

Comment: Did you forget to add the `bg-gradient-to-b` class?